# Merging two tables based on a column (partial match or comma separated column)?

Tags: mysql, r, excel, knime

I have two tables that their shared columns do not exactly match (differences in capital character or existence of some characters like comma,space and ...). How can I merge these two tables based on their shared column (in R, Knime, Excel-power query or sql)?

[image: Example Tables and Results]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example **Result** table it's not clear where the row

```
gene1 | go3 | 14
```

comes from, because there's no entry for `go3` in **Table2**. I'm assuming that's a mistake and you meant Table2 to include the row

```
go3 | 14
```

If that's correct, here's how to do this in KNIME:

[image: KNIME workflow]

The two **Table Creator** nodes just create the two tables with column names as shown in your example - replace these with your actual data sources. **Cell Splitter** splits column `Goes` using a comma as the delimiter. The **Unpivoting** node is configured like this:

[image: Unpivoting config]

and the **Joiner** like this:

[image: Joiner config]

All other settings were left as default. Add nodes to reorder and filter the columns in the Joiner output if you need to. Note that you'll see different `Goes_Arr[n]` columns depending on how many different values of `Goes` there are - the `Enforce exclusion` and `Enforce inclusion` settings make sure that Unpivoting handles this correctly.

This workflow should cope with whitespace between the commas, but I think you also mention differences in capital letters - if you need to handle these, pass each table through a **Case Converter** node to make them consistent.

Pivoting and unpivoting are hard to understand (IMHO - especially given the cryptic descriptions of their KNIME nodes) but very powerful. I recommend taking time to play around with these nodes to figure out how they work.